# Network meta-regression with R

Tags: meta-analysis

I need to perform a network meta-regression on the attached dataset (metareg).
Four interventions are assessed: cot, hfno, cpap, niv.

VARIABLES

id: study id
author: study author
prophylactic: first mediator variable (factor)
surgery: second mediator variable (factor)
risk: third mediator variable (factor)
setting: fourth mediator variable (factor)
intervention_1: first intervention tested (either cot, hfno, cpap, niv)
intervention_2: second intervention tested (either cot, hfno, cpap, niv)
n_tot: total number of patients in the study
n_1 : number of patients receiving the first intervention
n_2: number of patients receiving the second intervention
reeeti_1: number of patients developing the outcome with the first intervention
reeeti_2: number of patients developing the outcome with the second intervention
md_logor: mean difference or log odds ratio
se: standard error

DATASET (just reported the first 6 studies, but the dataset includes 33 studies)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYi3C.png)
I would need to perform 4 single meta-regressions based on the above-mentioned mediator variables (prophylactic, surgery, risk, setting).
Please please please, help me!
Thank you very much!
I could not perform the network meta-regression under a frequentist approach